# gcc and clang emit seemingly redundant function call

Tags: c, gcc, clang, x86-64, function-pointers

```
typedef struct foo
{
    void (*const t)(struct foo *f);
} foo;

void t(struct foo *f)
{
    
}

void (*const myt)(struct foo *f) = t;

foo f = {.t = t};

int main(void)
{
    f.t(&f);
    myt(&f);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the above code with x86-64 gcc 13.2 and clang 16.0.0 similar assembly code is generated. Shown below is gcc output.

```
t:
        ret
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:f
        call    [QWORD PTR f[rip]]
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
f:
        .quad   t
myt:
        .quad   t
```

Why do both compilers emit a call to `t` function when called through `struct foo` but not when called via `myt` function pointer? Why are the compilers not able to see that `t` function pointer in `struct foo` points to an empty function and eliminate the call all together? Since `f` is allocated statically and initialized at compile time such that its member `t`, a constant pointer that cannot be changed during runtime (without invoking undefined behaviour), points to an empty function `t`.

Comment: I guess it fails to see that `f.t` is const.

Comment: The same happens for `struct { const int i; } s = { 42 }; int foo() { return s.i; }`

Comment: @tstanisl Not entirely sure about C, but in C++ the `const` on `f.t` or `s.i` does not prevent them from evaluating to a different value than what the variables `f` or `s` were initialized with. (And in C++ this could already happen before `main`.) You'd need `const` top-level on the variables for that restriction.

Comment: I start to doubt if `f.t` is really a const object. It's indeed an const-qualified l-value expression but it does not mean that the memory region is actually const. Some citation from the standard will be very helpful here.

Comment: I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66554821/4989451) to related a question. It looks that whole `f` is **not** const qualified. The `const` for `t` just prevent using `f.t` to change the value of this object. It is a quite murky region of C standard.

Answer (score 10):

**GCC and Clang both provide mechanisms for arbitrary code to run before `main`**, so those compilers have to respect this possibility.  (Including linking with C++ libraries with static constructors, or [GNU C `__attribute__((constructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-constructor-function-attribute).)

**The global variable `foo f` is not `const`, so GCC and clang assume it could have been modified** before execution reaches `f.t(&f);`.  **Changing to `const foo f = ...;`** lets GCC and clang know that the function-pointer value is a compile-time constant, and inline through it and optimize away the empty function.  ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:12),source:%27typedef+struct+foo%0A%7B%0A//+I+changed+the+function+signatures+to+take+const+foo+*+to+avoid+warnings+with+const+foo+f%0A++++void+(*const+t)(const+struct+foo+*f)%3B%0A%7D+foo%3B%0A%0Avoid+t(const+struct+foo+*local_f)%0A%7B%0A++++(void)local_f%3B++//+silence+the+unused+warning%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+(*const+myt)(const+struct+foo+*f)+%3D+t%3B%0A%0A//static+++++//+not+visible+outside+the+compilation+unit%0Aconst++++//+making+the+global+const+allows+optimization.%0Afoo+f+%3D+%7B.t+%3D+t%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++f.t(0)%3B++++//+not+f.t(%26f)+so+it!%27s+clear+to+the+optimizer+the+address+of+f+doesn!%27t+escape%0A++++myt(0)%3B%0A%0A//+f.t(0)%3B+myt(%26f)%3B++//+lets+clang+-flto+optimize+away+both+calls,+but+still+not+GCC+-fwhole-program%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A/*%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0Avoid+startup(void)%7B%0A++++//f+%3D+(foo)%7BNULL%7D%3B+//+illegal%0A++++foo+tmp+%3D+%7BNULL%7D%3B%0A++++memcpy(%26f,+%26tmp,+sizeof(f))%3B++//+legal,+it+seems,+as+long+as+foo+f+isn!%27t+const+foo+f++(In+which+case+this+warns,+and+will+segfault+at+run-time)%0A++++//+actually+clang+emits+no+instructions+for+the+memcpy+in+the+UB+case+where+it!%27s+trying+to+write+const+foo+f.%0A%7D%0A*/%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-PIE+-fvisibility%3Dhidden%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,m:45.483586575357975,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:20.86403053915504,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-pie%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:33.652382885487,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

---

So what could code look like which modifies `f.t`?

Obviously it can't do `f.t = whatever` because the `.t` member is `const`.  GCC and clang also refuse to compile `f = (foo){NULL};` to replace the whole struct's value, complaining about the `const` member.  (Clang says *error: cannot assign to variable 'f' with const-qualified data member 't'*.  GCC uses the same error as with `const foo f`, *error: assignment of read-only variable 'f'*.)

**But they do allow `memcpy` without warnings** even from `-Wall -Wextra`, vs. they do warn if `f` is `const`.  (I used `NULL` as a placeholder just to avoid writing another valid function.  If you can change it to NULL, you can change it to a function that would do something when called.)

```
#include <string.h>
// Code like this could hypothetically run before main in another compilation unit
void startup(void){
    // f = (foo){NULL};    // illegal

    foo tmp = {NULL};
    memcpy(&f, &tmp, sizeof(f));  // legal, it seems, as long as foo f isn't const foo f
      //   (In which case this warns, and will segfault at run-time)
      // actually clang emits no instructions for the memcpy in the UB case where it's trying to write const foo f.
}
```

I haven't checked the ISO standard, but assuming GCC/clang's (lack of) warnings are consistent with what its optimizer assumes other code could have done, this explains why non-`const` `f` is not treated as having a known value in this case.

---

#### Why doesn't `static foo f` help?

Making it `static foo f` (in a compilation unit that doesn't define a `startup()` function to modify it) should allow constant-propagation, since nothing outside the compilation unit can see it, and nothing inside changes the value.

But even `gcc -fwhole-program` and GCC/clang `-flto` (disassembling the linked binary) fail to inline `f.t(&f)`, even though those options do let them inline `myt(&f)` for non-`const` non-`static` `myt`.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:92,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:92,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:92,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:92,startLineNumber:21),source:%27typedef+struct+foo%0A%7B%0A//+I+changed+the+function+signatures+to+take+const+foo+*+to+avoid+warnings+with+const+foo+f%0A++++void+(*const+t)(const+struct+foo+*f)%3B%0A%7D+foo%3B%0A%0Avoid+t(const+struct+foo+*local_f)%0A%7B%0A++++(void)local_f%3B++//+silence+the+unused+warning%0A%7D%0A%0A//+non-const,+but+-flto+or+-fwhole-program+can+see+nothing+modifies+it%0Avoid+(*myt)(const+struct+foo+*f)+%3D+t%3B%0A%0Astatic+++++//+not+visible+outside+the+compilation+unit%0A//const++++//+making+the+global+const+allows+optimization.%0Afoo+f+%3D+%7B.t+%3D+t%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++f.t(%26f)%3B++++//+passes+the+address+of+f+to+some+function+the+optimizer+isn!%27t+sure+of+yet%0A++++myt(%26f)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A/*%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0Avoid+startup(void)%7B%0A++++//f+%3D+(foo)%7BNULL%7D%3B+//+illegal%0A++++foo+tmp+%3D+%7BNULL%7D%3B%0A++++memcpy(%26f,+%26tmp,+sizeof(f))%3B++//+legal,+it+seems,+as+long+as+foo+f+isn!%27t+const+foo+f++(In+which+case+this+warns,+and+will+segfault+at+run-time)%0A++++//+actually+clang+emits+no+instructions+for+the+memcpy+in+the+UB+case+where+it!%27s+trying+to+write+const+foo+f.%0A%7D%0A*/%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-PIE+-fvisibility%3Dhidden+-fwhole-program%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,m:40.04260726454541,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:26.198659999249706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-flto+++-fPIC+-fvisibility%3Ddefault%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:33.758732736204884,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)).

Changing the calls to `f.t(0);` and `myt(0)` allows GCC and clang to optimize away both calls!  (With `static foo f` and `const myt`, or with `-fwhole-program` or `-flto`.)  **I think passing `&f` as an arg was defeating escape analysis**, even though compilers could in theory have proved that the call target was still always the `t()` defined in this compilation unit, which didn't actually let the address escape outside the compilation unit.

```
// or non-const is the same if we're using -flto or -fwhole-program
void (*const myt)(const struct foo *f) = t;
static foo f = {.t = t};

int main(void)
{
    f.t(0);    // not f.t(&f) so it's clear to the optimizer the address of f doesn't escape
    myt(0);

// f.t(0); myt(&f);  // lets clang -flto optimize away both calls, but still not GCC -fwhole-program
}
```

In C, it's not UB for `main` to get called again from inside the program.  So if `f.t(&f)` changes `f.t`, the next execution of `main` (e.g. from an `__attribute__((destructor))` function in another compilation unit) would be a call to a different function.  That's not actually possible here, but it's easy to imagine that a compiler might have got caught in a loop trying to prove that and given up.  (`f` has its address taken and passed to a function call, by a non-`static` function in this compilation unit, which normally means the address escapes.  Seeing that it goes to `t()` which doesn't change `f` would require inlining to happen before it finished escape analysis, but it can't inline through a function pointer unless escape analysis can prove it knows which function is being called.)

`myt` on the other hand is truly `const` so is easy to optimize away.  Even if we make it not `const` or `static`, with `-flto` or `-fwhole-program` it's easy for the compile to see that nothing in this compilation unit (or any compilation unit with LTO) changes it, and `&myt` isn't passed as a function arg so obviously doesn't escape.  (Without `-flto` or `const`/`static`, constprop through global `myt` can't happen either.)

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:15),source:%27typedef+struct+foo%0A%7B%0A//+I+changed+the+function+signatures+to+take+const+foo+*+to+avoid+warnings+with+const+foo+f%0A++++void+(*const+t)(const+struct+foo+*f)%3B%0A%7D+foo%3B%0A%0Avoid+t(const+struct+foo+*local_f)%0A%7B%0A++++(void)local_f%3B++//+silence+the+unused+warning%0A%7D%0A%0A//+non-const,+but+-flto+or+-fwhole-program+can+see+nothing+modifies+it%0Avoid+(*const+myt)(const+struct+foo+*f)+%3D+t%3B%0A%0Astatic+++++//+not+visible+outside+the+compilation+unit%0A//const++++//+making+the+global+const+allows+optimization.%0Afoo+f+%3D+%7B.t+%3D+t%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++f.t(0)%3B++++//+not+f.t(%26f)+so+it!%27s+clear+to+the+optimizer+the+address+of+f+doesn!%27t+escape%0A++++myt(0)%3B%0A%0A//+f.t(0)%3B+myt(%26f)%3B++//+lets+clang+-flto+optimize+away+both+calls,+but+still+not+GCC+-fwhole-program%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A/*%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0Avoid+startup(void)%7B%0A++++//f+%3D+(foo)%7BNULL%7D%3B+//+illegal%0A++++foo+tmp+%3D+%7BNULL%7D%3B%0A++++memcpy(%26f,+%26tmp,+sizeof(f))%3B++//+legal,+it+seems,+as+long+as+foo+f+isn!%27t+const+foo+f++(In+which+case+this+warns,+and+will+segfault+at+run-time)%0A++++//+actually+clang+emits+no+instructions+for+the+memcpy+in+the+UB+case+where+it!%27s+trying+to+write+const+foo+f.%0A%7D%0A*/%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-PIE+-fvisibility%3Dhidden%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,m:45.483586575357975,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:20.86403053915504,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-pie%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:33.652382885487,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) - with `main` doing `f.t(0);myt(0);`, `*const myt` and `static foo f` are sufficient to let both GCC and clang optimize away both calls, even without `-flto` or `-fwhole-program`.  Unless this compilation unit defines a function like `startup()` that does a `memcpy` to `&f`.

But with non-`static` `foo f`, that optimization is once again impossible since it could have been modified even before the first / only execution of `main`.

BTW, my Godbolt links have `-fvisibility=hidden` just to make sure symbol-interposition isn't a possibility, which would be another way for a non-`static` variable's value to be different from the initializer in the source.  But that's already not possible for globals in the main executable, only relevant with `-fPIC` to compile code that's safe for a shared library.

Comment: "so GCC and clang assume it could have been modified" Except a function pointer of read-only type `* const` cannot be modified - doing so would invoke undefined behavior. Adding qualifiers to struct members rather than the whole struct often causes unexpected trouble, in my experience.

Comment: *Except a function pointer of read-only type `* const` cannot be modified - doing so would invoke undefined behavior.* As I showed, replacing the object-representation of `f` via `memcpy` is something that GCC and Clang's optimizers think is allowed when the whole `f` isn't `const`.  Regardless of what the ISO standard says, that's what explains the behaviour of their optimizers.  If they define behaviour beyond what ISO C permits, they can't also assume it doesn't happen.

Comment: @Lundin: Good advice to apply `const` to the whole variable, when you can though.  As this shows, applying it only to struct members doesn't always help the optimizer as much as one might expect.  (It will still stop `f = (foo){0}` from compiling, though, as my answer points out.  What kind of "unexpected trouble" have you seen?)

Comment: I think you are allowed to change _padding bytes_ of the struct through memcpy but not any const qualified members. So if you have a habit of storing secret messages in padding bytes, then some other translation unit may be assumed to have changed that message.

Comment: As for unexpected trouble, this very example? Or declaring one member  `const int* x`, another `int* y` and then creating a `const` struct and assume that `y` is now const-correct, although in reality we've changed the members to `const int* const x` and `int * const y`... maybe not what the programmer had expected.

Comment: Oh and what happens when you malloc a struct with const qualified members... another such weird scenario which wasn't anticipated by anyone.

Comment: The assignment is disallowed in [6.3.2.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1) as a struct with a const member is not a modifiable lvalue. However, begin non-modifiable l-value does not make an object immutable. Arrays are a good example.

Comment: @Lundin, *a function pointer of read-only type \* const cannot be modified - doing so would invoke undefined behavior*. The problem is if `f.t` is indeed a const-qualified region in memory even though `f.t` is const-qualified l-value expression.

Comment: @Lundin "wasn't anticipated by anyone" Not really. Allocated objects have no declared type and you can just access them using any type lvalue you want. It's in the standard.

Comment: @tstanisl Non-const members are modifiable lvalues though, just like array elements, so a struct with a const member is not necessarily immutable. But a const member is a const member. It is an object having a const-qualified declared type (or so the standard makes me believe). It doesn't really matters though for the purpose of this answer because gcc and clang clearly treat the struct as modifiable (they place it in .data rather than .rodata). Whether it is justified standard-wise is a different question.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes but as such you can _only_ assign a value to it with memcpy, ironically - not by assignment. Which is BS, the language shouldn't work like that. Qualifiers of struct members, the effective type rule, the malloc interface - all of it is _very badly designed_, leading to nothing but obscure and/or dangerous code - by language design.

Comment: @Lundin No, you can also cast the pointer and assign, no problem with that whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Cast what pointer, how? `read_only* ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr); *ptr = (read_only){ .x=1 };` would be a constraint violation, where `x` is a `const` member.

Comment: @Lundin `*(int*)(ptr->x) = 42;` since an object that `ptr->x` points to is an allocated object and has no declared type.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Ah but now the effective type is `int`. Not a struct containing an `int`. Not a `const int`. Dysfunctionally, the effective type rules do not properly address qualifiers, nor enough of how containers ("aggregate types") are supposed to work.

Comment: @Lundin yeah  this is not well-defined, not only because of the qualifiers but in general. Still, at least memcpy works.

Comment: @Lundin no wait, seems to be OK. *If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then blah blah* We are not storing a value into `*ptr`, but into its subobject. The effective type of `*ptr` remains the same. The effective type of `ptr->x` changes but it's ok, we still can access it through `ptr->x` because it has a const-qualified version of the effective type. Or maybe not, the wording is too vague.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The standard isn't clear. In fact `*ptr` has no effective type at all in this example. These rules have been a mess since C99 and nobody wants to fix them, apparently.

Comment: @Lundin This is not full code, you supposedly initialise `*ptr` somewhere. But yes it's a mess.